# extract values from string in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

​I have this string in one of my excel fields:

```
"a:3:{
i:0;
a:1:{s:10:"Adult Name";s:11:"Mohamed";}
i:1;
a:1:{s:10:"Adult Name";s:11:"Mathew";}
i:2;
a:1:{s:10:"Adult Name";s:11:"Paul";
i:3;
a:1:{s:10:"Adult Name";s:11:"John";}
}"
```

I want to extract the names into seprate fields like:

```
   A         B
```

1. **Adult 1**: Mohamed
2. **Adult 2**: Mathew
3. **Adult 3**: Paul
4. **Adult 4**: John

Comment: just clarifying, that whole string is in one cell?

Comment: Is it always 4 names or do the number of names vary.  Is the syntax/structure always the same

Answer (score 0):

[image: Example]

You string was placed in F5.
A5 was manually entered and dragged down.  Since there was a digit in the last character, excel automatically augmented the number by 1 as it was dragged.

I identified a recurring character sequence that started before every name and called that the start tag.  I did the same for a character that showed up at the end of a name.  Those values were placed in C3 and D3 respectively.

Using the following formula I then found the starting position in the string for each start tag provided in C3:

```
=SEARCH(C$3,$F$5,C4+1)
```

The C4+1 tells the find to start from the next character of the previous search results.  As such C4 needs to be blank.

Using the following formula I then found the end of the name using the end tag value in D3:

```
=SEARCH(D$3,$F$5,C5+LEN($C$3))
```

once the start and end positions were known, the name were pulled from the string in F5 using the following formula:

```
=MID($F$5,C5+LEN($C$3),D5-C5-LEN($C$3))
```

These formulas were placed in row 5 and copied down to match the list "Adult #"